# SQL Как вставить строку в таблицу, если ее там еще нет

Tags: sql

Подскажите, только начал изучать SQL. У меня есть таблица `torgi` в ней есть 3 колонки `id`, `id_torgi` и `id_company`. И я хочу записывать данные в поля если в двух полях `id_torg` и `id_company` нет таких значений, если же есть, то ничего не записывать.

Comment: сделайте уникальный составной ключ из этих двух полей. Запрос делайте либо `INSERT IGNORE ...`, либо `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: ```INSERT INTO torgi (id_torgi, id_company)
   VALUES (23, 5)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_torgi = 23 AND id_company = 5;```  Если я правильно вас понял, то у меня почему-то он все равно добавляет строку новую с такими же значениями

Comment: а вы составной уникальный ключ добавили?